# XDocument commands for shorthand xml?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I am using Xdocument.Descendents(xnode).value.single() to read the value of elements in standard xml, but it won't work for shorthand like

{Node Value= "value" / }
(replace curly with square)

Does anyone know what code I need? Also to change the value and save the xml?

Could you tell me how to even Google this? Does the shorthand xml have a proper name? Is there a list for the XDocument library for the code around this? Or do I need another xml linq?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you seeing this in the debugger?   What do you expect to see?

Comment: By 'shothand XML' did you men *XPath* (google it)?

Comment: Post the XML and the node you are trying to get.

Comment: Hey so someone has answered me on another forum and said it's not "shorthand" but it's just an empty element with an "attribute"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XDocument.Descendants(Xnode).Attributes(Xname).Single.Value

and to change it

XElement.Element(Xnode).Attribute(Xname).Value = "something"